# Objective-C Database connection

Tags: mysql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have to realise a sort of Library in objective-C which help to store any object in a Database, with introspection. But I'm having some trouble with the database connection.

I found some tutorials to do this with SQLite on an iphone with Obj-C, but not on OSX in an application.

I would like to provide a Sqlite connection and a MySql connection (to meet the user's preference).  Is it possible to do this in an Objective-C command line tool ? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: What you *really* want is CoreData and [here's a tutorial for you](http://programming.wonderhowto.com/how-to/build-simple-core-data-application-mac-os-x-218962/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoah.   That is a mighty big request;   there are *entire companies* devoted to nothing but object relational mapping layers.

There is no way that you can do this through introspection only with arbitrary objects.   First, there isn't enough metadata available at runtime to effectively serialize all types, much less map them to a database.   Secondly, even if there was, you still have to deal with exactly how much of the object graph to persist.

You really need some kind of modeling information that describes specifically the objects to be persisted, how they will be persisted, and how much of the object graph you need to persist.

I.e. you are effectively asking to re-invent EOF, the predecessor to CoreData, that provided a much more generic Object to Relational mapping layer.

To gain perspective on what you are asking, I'd suggest reading the first few chapters of the [Enterprise Objects Framework Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_4.0/System/Documentation/Developer/EnterpriseObjects/Guide/EOFDevGuide.pdf).

Core Data does provide an [incremental storage API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Introduction/Introduction.html) that would greatly simplify your implementation goals, but will require that you model your data layer properly as a Core Data model.

Comment: Thx for Help :) I'll read this closely !

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about MySql but about sqlite, you should use FMDB:
[FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
FMDB can use for iOS, MAC OSX (arc and non-arc)
It's great framework.

Good luck

Comment: Thank a lot ! I'll use it :)